# Как принять человека в канал телеграмм и написать ему сообщение от лица бота?

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

Стоит задача: когда человек вступает в канал, то нужно чтобы бот (если нужно, то бот в канале будет состоять) писал сообщение в личку. При этом ботов, которые пишут сообщения в лс >1 и вход можно сделать как с одобрениями администратора, так и без.

Использовать telebot или aiogram?

Comment: Бот не может первым писать сообщение в ЛС юзеру. ЭТО НЕВОЗМОЖНО   https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots#cem-bot-otlicaetsa-ot-obycnogo-akkaunta

Comment: https://t.me/joinchat/hT-xGiOX9M8zMmJi
А это сбой в матрице или че?

Comment: не ответил бот(

Comment: есть подозрение, что дело именно в том, что канал закрытый

Comment: да! Объясни пожалуйста как!

Comment: куда отписать тебе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PS. К слову это такой себе способ сделать так чтобы бот писал первым. Забавно.

Итак чтобы повторить то что ты кидал по ссылке, я немного помучался. Собственно шаги.

1. делаем бота в ботфазере
2. даем боту возможность читать все сообщения (Group Privacy)
3. создаем канал
4. добавляем бота как администратора
5. заходим в управление каналом - пригласительные ссылки - создать новую ссылку - ставим галку Заявки на вступление - ДОБАВИТЬ
6. теперь переходим к коду бота

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def start1(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    # тут мы принимаем юзера в канал
    await update.approve()
    # а тут отправляем сообщение
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=update.from_user.id, text="текст сообщения бота в лс юзеру")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: А писал, что невозможно)))